# How can I grab specific SHA-1 hashes from remote repositories?

Tags: git, git-remote, git-fetch, git-ls-remote

This script iterates multiple Git repositories in order to get their latest commit `SHA-1` per branch.
These commands are launched inside an arbitrary `.git` directory, so Git commands can be invoked without actually cloning any other repository.

```
git ls-remote https://$Username:$Password@git.testgit.com/r/repository1 > tmp/repository1
.
.
.
git ls-remote https://$Username:$Password@git.testgit.com/r/repository100 > tmp/repository100
```

A typical output per `git ls-remote` command would be (e.g. for `repository1`):

```
7898b741a5c6b7bd5ks93478600165905c3e96d2    HEAD
57e9fm46caf48eb82863e0278ee17c9332ee20d4    refs/heads/development
7898b741a5c6b7bd5ks93478600165905c3e96d2    refs/heads/master
```

Then each `SHA-1` can be extracted and saved for instance as `current_repository1_ref_heads_development=57e9fm46caf48eb82863e0278ee17c9332ee20d4`

I'm wondering if it's possible to grab a `SHA-1` that's not a `heads` (latest) and was pushed at a specific time ago (e.g. 60 minutes), so I can compare if `current_repository1_ref_heads_development = previous_repository1_ref_heads_development`, without cloning any of these repositories at all.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Probably no, but if you save all of your results, then 60 minutes from now you can do that compare... :D